# Failed to resolve dependencies from parent project Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have the following problem

I have a project1 that use quickblox sdk as following

```
dependencies {
compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:3.3.1@aar"
    compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:3.3.1@aar"
    compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.3.1@aar"
    compile"com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.1@aar"
    compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.1@aar") {
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

Then I have used this project1 as library dependancies in project2

Now I am getting thes error `failed to resolve dependencies`

I am using other sdks and all of them are working in the children project without any problem but I do not know why quickblox is not working

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: How are you adding the project1 as dependencies in project2?

Comment: compile project(':project1')

Comment: You can use QuickBlox Android SDK libs without '@aar' for include transitive dependencies. Your case mast be work because it works in QuickBlox's project Q-municate (see link https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android/tree/update_sdk_3_2_0)